# Can anyone please explain how the all magento command work in magento2(I want to undesrstand backend process)?

Tags: magento2, command, workflow

Can anyone please explain how the all magento command work in magento2(I want to understand backend process)

Like:

IF I am running command 
**php bin/magento module:status**
which file will affect and how it display?

I want to know about all the commands which we mostly use by command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ObjectManagerProvider.php is the starting point of initializing all commands with application run

> setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/ObjectManagerProvider.php

Here `createCliCommands()` function creates cli commands and initialize them with application instance

`createCliCommands()` function gets list of command instances from `getCommands()` function which returns all command classes

You can check all command classes from `getCommandsClasses()`

> setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/CommandList.php

Here is the list of all command classes

```
\Magento\Setup\Console\Command\AdminUserCreateCommand::class,
\Magento\Setup\Console\Command\BackupCommand::class,
\Magento\Setup\Console\Command\ConfigSetCommand::class,
\Magento\Setup\Console\Command\CronRunCommand::class,
\Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DbDataUpgradeCommand::class,
\Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DbSchemaUpgradeCommand::class,
\Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DbStatusCommand::class,
\Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DependenciesShowFrameworkCommand::class,
\Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DependenciesShowModulesCircularCommand::class,
\Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DependenciesShowModulesCommand::class,
\Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DiCompileCommand::class,
\Magento\Setup\Console\Command\GenerateFixturesCommand::class,
\Magento\Setup\Console\Command\I18nCollectPhrasesCommand::class,
\Magento\Setup\Console\Command\I18nPackCommand::class,
\Magento\Setup\Console\Command\InfoAdminUriCommand::class,
\Magento\Setup\Console\Command\InfoBackupsListCommand::class,
\Magento\Setup\Console\Command\InfoCurrencyListCommand::class,
\Magento\Setup\Console\Command\InfoLanguageListCommand::class,
\Magento\Setup\Console\Command\InfoTimezoneListCommand::class,
\Magento\Setup\Console\Command\InstallCommand::class,
\Magento\Setup\Console\Command\InstallStoreConfigurationCommand::class,
\Magento\Setup\Console\Command\ModuleEnableCommand::class,
\Magento\Setup\Console\Command\ModuleDisableCommand::class,
\Magento\Setup\Console\Command\ModuleStatusCommand::class,
\Magento\Setup\Console\Command\ModuleUninstallCommand::class,
\Magento\Setup\Console\Command\MaintenanceAllowIpsCommand::class,
\Magento\Setup\Console\Command\MaintenanceDisableCommand::class,
\Magento\Setup\Console\Command\MaintenanceEnableCommand::class,
\Magento\Setup\Console\Command\MaintenanceStatusCommand::class,
\Magento\Setup\Console\Command\RollbackCommand::class,
\Magento\Setup\Console\Command\UpgradeCommand::class,
\Magento\Setup\Console\Command\UninstallCommand::class,
\Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DeployStaticContentCommand::class
```

Command `module:status` has been declare `ModuleStatusCommand.php`

> setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/ModuleStatusCommand.php

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $moduleList = $this->objectManagerProvider->get()->create(\Magento\Framework\Module\ModuleList::class);
    $output->writeln('<info>List of enabled modules:</info>');
    $enabledModules = $moduleList->getNames();
    if (count($enabledModules) === 0) {
        $output->writeln('None');
    } else {
        $output->writeln(join("\n", $enabledModules));
    }
    $output->writeln('');

    $fullModuleList = $this->objectManagerProvider->get()->create(\Magento\Framework\Module\FullModuleList::class);
    $output->writeln("<info>List of disabled modules:</info>");
    $disabledModules = array_diff($fullModuleList->getNames(), $enabledModules);
    if (count($disabledModules) === 0) {
        $output->writeln('None');
    } else {
        $output->writeln(join("\n", $disabledModules));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The command 'module:status' has been declared in

> setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/ModuleStatusCommand.php

Use a grep command to find out in which module the Console Command is declared:

> grep -r 'module:status' vendor/magento/

and then in this case it is in magento2-base setup which will be placed in the setup folder during installation.